# In Between causes my query to return "wrong" values

Tags: mysql

I have a little problem right here...

So all in all I have exactly two tables:

```
* resources (ID, resourcetype_ID, chunk_ID, position)

* chunks (ID, x, y)
```

The first one stores some rows which belongs to the certain chunk.
The second one just stores all the chunks with a different set of x and y as some kind of position.

My goal is to select all the resources that belong to a certain range of chunks.
But I have made a mistake somewhere. I always get the wrong x and y positions, when I select the resources.

```
SELECT resources.*, chunks.x, chunks.y 
FROM resources, chunks 
where chunk_ID in (SELECT ID 
                   FROM chunks 
                   where x between 17185-1 and 17185+1 
                     and y between 10846-1 and 10846+1) 
group by ID
```

This query above returns all the resources that belongs to the different chunks. But the returned x and y position is for all of them the same. Why does this happen?

(As you can see the resources with "chunk_ID" = 1 have the same x and y as the resources with "chunk_ID" = 5 ... even if those chunks have completely different x and y pairs...)

[image]

Normally all resources should have different x and y values regarding to the chunk they belong to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query:

```
SELECT resources.*, chunks.x, chunks.y 
FROM resources, chunks 
where chunk_ID in (SELECT ID 
                   FROM chunks 
                   where x between 17185-1 and 17185+1 
                     and y between 10846-1 and 10846+1) 
group by ID
```

I see several issues:

- The two tables in the `FROM` clause are not joined (that's the reason for the irrelevant results you get, the two tables are correlated through the subquery<sup>*</sup> but the `FROM` clause introduces an additional non-correlated `chunks` reference which produces all these unrelated results):

  ```
  FROM resources, chunks
  ```

  Join them:

  ```
  FROM resources JOIN chunks ON resources.chunk_id = chunks.id
  ```
- Since `chunks` is in the `FROM` clause, we don't need<sup>*</sup> the subquery no more, to check `x` and `y`:

  ```
  where chunk_ID in (SELECT ID 
                     FROM chunks 
                     where x between 17185-1 and 17185+1 
                       and y between 10846-1 and 10846+1)
  ```

  Simplify `WHERE`:

  ```
  WHERE chunks.x BETWEEN 17185-1 AND 17185+1 
    AND chunks.y BETWEEN 10846-1 AND 10846+1
  ```
- You have `SELECT *` combined with `GROUP BY`. This is a recipe for spurious, wrong results.

  Just remove the `GROUP BY`.

The query becomes after using all the above comments (and some polishing with table aliases):

```
-- Suggested query
SELECT r.*, c.x, c.y 
FROM resources AS r
     JOIN chunks AS c
     ON r.chunk_id = c.id  
WHERE c.x BETWEEN 17185-1 AND 17185+1 
  AND c.y BETWEEN 10846-1 AND 10846+1 ;
```

---

<sup>*</sup> Just for completeness, we could have kept the `IN` subquery and remove `chunks` from the `FROM` clause.

This would have the restriction that we couldn't have any column from `chunks` in the `SELECT` list - and more likely worse performance than the `JOIN` query:

```
-- Don't use this one
SELECT r.* 
FROM resources AS r
WHERE r.chunk_d IN 
      ( SELECT c.id
        FROM chunks AS c
        WHERE c.x BETWEEN 17185-1 AND 17185+1
          AND c.y BETWEEN 10846-1 AND 10846+1
      ) ;
```